# return each element from a list-of-dictionaries if a list-of-dictionaries contained within has a specific key or list is empty

Tags: json, scripting, unique, jq

Considering the following data structure, I'm looking to use jq to return each document based on the following criteria:

1. Return all documents whose `members` array contains a key `subPath`
2. Return all documents whose `members` array does NOT contain a key `subPath`
3. Return all documents whose `members` array is empty

```
[
  {
    "alternate_mode": "global-availability",
    "dynamic_ratio": "no",
    "enabled": "yes",
    "fallback_mode": "return-to-dns",
    "full_path": "/Common/a2ws-test.ree.se.net_pool",
    "load_balancing_mode": "global-availability",
    "manual_resume": "no",
    "max_answers_returned": 1,
    "members": [
      {
        "name": "a2ws-test.ree.se.net-443-vs",
        "partition": "Common",
        "subPath": "f5-tstltm-dmz-dc1-pair:/Common",
        "enabled": "yes",
        "limitMaxBps": 0,
        "limitMaxBpsStatus": "disabled",
        "limitMaxConnections": 0,
        "limitMaxConnectionsStatus": "disabled",
        "limitMaxPps": 0,
        "limitMaxPpsStatus": "disabled",
        "monitor": "default",
        "ratio": 1,
        "disabled": "no",
        "member_order": 0
      },
      {
        "name": "dc2-a2ws-test.ree.se.net-443-vs",
        "partition": "Common",
        "subPath": "f5-tstltm-dmz-dc2-pair:/Common",
        "enabled": "yes",
        "limitMaxBps": 0,
        "limitMaxBpsStatus": "disabled",
        "limitMaxConnections": 0,
        "limitMaxConnectionsStatus": "disabled",
        "limitMaxPps": 0,
        "limitMaxPpsStatus": "disabled",
        "monitor": "default",
        "ratio": 1,
        "disabled": "no",
        "member_order": 1
      }
    ],
    "name": "a2ws-test.ree.se.net_pool",
    "partition": "Common",
    "qos_hit_ratio": 5,
    "qos_hops": 0,
    "qos_kilobytes_second": 3,
    "qos_lcs": 30,
    "qos_packet_rate": 1,
    "qos_rtt": 50,
    "qos_topology": 0,
    "qos_vs_capacity": 0,
    "qos_vs_score": 0,
    "ttl": 30,
    "verify_member_availability": "yes"
  },
  {
    "alternate_mode": "round-robin",
    "dynamic_ratio": "no",
    "enabled": "yes",
    "fallback_mode": "return-to-dns",
    "full_path": "/Common/aci-apic.ree.se.net_pool",
    "load_balancing_mode": "round-robin",
    "manual_resume": "no",
    "max_answers_returned": 1,
    "members": [
      {
        "name": "prd_dc1_servers:aci-apic01.ree.se.net",
        "partition": "Common",
        "enabled": "yes",
        "limitMaxBps": 0,
        "limitMaxBpsStatus": "disabled",
        "limitMaxConnections": 0,
        "limitMaxConnectionsStatus": "disabled",
        "limitMaxPps": 0,
        "limitMaxPpsStatus": "disabled",
        "monitor": "default",
        "ratio": 1,
        "disabled": "no",
        "member_order": 0
      },
      {
        "name": "prd_dc1_servers:aci-apic02.ree.se.net",
        "partition": "Common",
        "enabled": "yes",
        "limitMaxBps": 0,
        "limitMaxBpsStatus": "disabled",
        "limitMaxConnections": 0,
        "limitMaxConnectionsStatus": "disabled",
        "limitMaxPps": 0,
        "limitMaxPpsStatus": "disabled",
        "monitor": "default",
        "ratio": 1,
        "disabled": "no",
        "member_order": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "prd_dc2_servers:aci-apic03.ree.se.net",
        "partition": "Common",
        "enabled": "yes",
        "limitMaxBps": 0,
        "limitMaxBpsStatus": "disabled",
        "limitMaxConnections": 0,
        "limitMaxConnectionsStatus": "disabled",
        "limitMaxPps": 0,
        "limitMaxPpsStatus": "disabled",
        "monitor": "default",
        "ratio": 1,
        "disabled": "no",
        "member_order": 2
      }
    ],
    "name": "aci-apic.ree.se.net_pool",
    "partition": "Common",
    "qos_hit_ratio": 5,
    "qos_hops": 0,
    "qos_kilobytes_second": 3,
    "qos_lcs": 30,
    "qos_packet_rate": 1,
    "qos_rtt": 50,
    "qos_topology": 0,
    "qos_vs_capacity": 0,
    "qos_vs_score": 0,
    "ttl": 30,
    "verify_member_availability": "yes"
  },
  {
    "alternate_mode": "global-availability",
    "dynamic_ratio": "no",
    "enabled": "yes",
    "fallback_mode": "return-to-dns",
    "full_path": "/Common/b2b.ree.se.net_pool",
    "load_balancing_mode": "global-availability",
    "manual_resume": "no",
    "max_answers_returned": 1,
    "members": [],
    "name": "b2b.ree.se.net_pool",
    "partition": "Common",
    "qos_hit_ratio": 5,
    "qos_hops": 0,
    "qos_kilobytes_second": 3,
    "qos_lcs": 30,
    "qos_packet_rate": 1,
    "qos_rtt": 50,
    "qos_topology": 0,
    "qos_vs_capacity": 0,
    "qos_vs_score": 0,
    "ttl": 30,
    "verify_member_availability": "yes"
  }
]
```

For brevity, I'm picking off the `name` key to demonstrate what's returned.  Note multiples / duplicates are being returned for #1 and #2, when what I want is the single document.

For #1:

```
 ➜  jq -r '.[] | select(.members[] | has("subPath")).name' test.json 
a2ws-test.ree.se.net_pool
a2ws-test.ree.se.net_pool
```

For #2:

```
 ➜  jq -r '.[] | select(.members[] | has("subPath") | not).name' test.json    
aci-apic.ree.se.net_pool
aci-apic.ree.se.net_pool
aci-apic.ree.se.net_pool
```

For #3:

```
 ➜  jq -r '.[] | select(.members[] | length == 0)' test.json
 ➜
```

In the end, I'm wanting to query this json as aforementioned, and create yaml output from it, something like:

```
echo "# Discovered Members"
## Discovered Members have the key "subPath"
## look for and only return those json documents
cat test.json | jq -r '.[] | select(.members[] | has("subPath")) |
      "- name: " + .name,
      "  state: " + .enabled,
      "  type: a",
      "  preferred_lb_method: " + .load_balancing_mode,
      "  alternate_lb_method: " + .alternate_mode,
      "  fallback_lb_method: " + .fallback_mode,
      "  max_answers_returned: " + (.max_answers_returned | tostring),
      "  ttl: " + (.ttl | tostring),
      "  members:", (.members[] |
      "    - server: " + (.subPath | split(":") | first),
      "      virtual_server: /Common/" + .name,
      "      state: " + .enabled,
      "      member_order: " + (.member_order | tostring),
      "      ratio: " + (.ratio | tostring),
      "      monitor: " + .monitor)' \
    | sed 's/state: yes/state: present/g' \
    | sed 's/state: no/state: disabled/g'

echo "# Static Members"
# Static Members DO NOT have the key "subPath"
# look for and only return those json documents
jq -r '.[] | select(.members[] | has("subPath") | not) |
      "- name: " + .name,
      "  state: " + .enabled,
      "  type: a",
      "  preferred_lb_method: " + .load_balancing_mode,
      "  alternate_lb_method: " + .alternate_mode,
      "  fallback_lb_method: " + .fallback_mode,
      "  max_answers_returned: " + (.max_answers_returned | tostring),
      "  ttl: " + (.ttl | tostring),
      "  members:", (.members[] |
      "    - server: " + (.name | split(":") | first),
      "      virtual_server: " + (.name | split(":") | last),
      "      state: " + .enabled,
      "      member_order: " + (.member_order | tostring),
      "      ratio: " + (.ratio | tostring),
      "      monitor: " + .monitor)' test.json \
    | sed 's/dev_dc1_servers/static-f5-dev-dc1-servers/g' \
    | sed 's/dev_dc2_servers/static-f5-dev-dc2-servers/g' \
    | sed 's/tst_dc1_servers/static-f5-tst-dc1-servers/g' \
    | sed 's/tst_dc2_servers/static-f5-tst-dc2-servers/g' \
    | sed 's/prd_dc1_servers/static-f5-prd-dc1-servers/g' \
    | sed 's/prd_dc2_servers/static-f5-prd-dc2-servers/g' \
    | sed 's/state: yes/state: present/g' \
    | sed 's/state: no/state: disabled/g'

# those that do not have members defined, but still need to be represented as objects to consider
# figure out the jq first
```

I've tried piping to `unique` with no success which tells me I'm querying incorrectly.

How would I go about returning each document from a list of dictionaries based on whether or not a list contained within each dictionary does or does not contain a specific key name, and find those whose list is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #1 and #2, it's not clear to me whether you want the first item satisfying the condition, or the collection of distinct items that satisfy the condition.

For the first item, you could use `first`:

```
first(.[] | select(.members[] | has("subPath")).name)
```

For the distinct items, you could of course use `unique`:

```
map(select(.members[] | has("subPath")).name ) | unique[]
```

Similarly for #2.

For #3, you need to check `.members|length`, not `.members|length`:

```
.[] | select(.members | length == 0)
```

Comment: My intention was to inquire for the distinct items.  Thanks for pointing out the varying options in considering how the data could be processed.  This worked perfectly for me, thank you!